# Is it possible to overload the *static_cast* operator?

Tags: c++, casting

I have defined a class *A*, the actual properties are irrelevant. Is it possible to define a specialization of the `static_cast<class T>(int)` operator to convert from integers to class A?

So far I have been doing this by defining a *convert* function, such as `A convert(int)`. But I would rather use `static_cast` for consistency with other conversions.

Is it possible?
I also want to avoid implicit conversions, which is why I'm not doing this through *A*'s constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`static_cast` is a language keyword and you can't do anything to change that. However you *can* achieve what you what with an explicit converting constructor:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    explicit Foo(int bar) { }  // Can't be called implicitly, CAN be invoked with `static_cast`.
};
```

This works because the language defines `static_cast`'s behavior in terms of object construction, invoking conversions as appropriate.

Comment: `Foo`'s constructor need to be public. Also this solution doesn't require to use `static_cast`, explicitly using type like `Foo(1)` works as well.

Answer (score 10):

`static_cast` is a keyword, so there's nothing you can overload or override there. If you want to provide code that controls how integers are transformed into `class A` instances, write an appropriate constructor of the form `A::A(int)`.

**Update:** If you want to avoid implicit conversions, you can make this constructor [`explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1y7x448%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Somehow I didn't quite read the last sentence of the question, apologies.

Comment: Is the fact that it's a keyword relevant?  So are `new` and `delete`.

Comment: `new` and `delete` are operators, a subtle difference.

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to avoid implicit conversions. Why don't you use explicit keyword?

Answer (score 2):

If `A` has a `A(int)` conversion constructor it will be invoked by C++ when you use `static_cast<A>` on objects of type `int`.

Comment: Why would a constructor of `A` be used to cast an `A` to an `int`?

Comment: Being `explicit` doesn't prevent `static_cast`, only implicit conversions.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I understand that.  I was commenting on sharptooth's answer, read it carefully.

Comment: If you write `static_cast`, it doesn't matter if the constructor is `explicit` or not.  And if you write `static_cast<int>`, no constructor of `A` will be called.  Ever.  To support conversion of `A` to `int`, you need a conversion operator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.  You can't define an `operator static_cast()`, but
`static_cast` will always call either a constructor or a conversion
operator: to support `int` to `MyClass`, provide `MyClass` with a
constructor which can be called with an `int`; to support `MyClass` to
`int`, provide `MyClass` with an `operator int() const` function.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to define a specialization of the static_cast(int) operator to convert from integers to class A

No. `static_cast` is a keyword, not a template, or function.

However, in your class `A`, you can write a constructor which takes `int` if you want that behavior.

```
struct A
{
   A(int i) {}
};

A a = 10; //automatic conversion!
```

Or if you want some syntactic sugar which should look like a cast, then you can do this:

```
template<typename To, typename From>
To type_cast(From from)
{
    return To(from);
}
```

then use it as:

```
A a = type_cast<A>(10); //but why would you do that?
```

But why would you do that? I don't see any advantage in doing that; so I discourage you from writing such function template. I showed you it just for experimental and educational purpose. Such code should not find place in real code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a constructor taking an `int`?

```
struct MyInteger
{
    MyInteger(int i);
};

int main()
{
    MyInteger i = 1234;
}
```