# Overload a C++ reference cast (downcasting inheritance)

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, downcast, static-cast

Is is possible to overload a reference cast in C++?

I've got code I can't touch in the format:

```
void someMethod(Parent& parentReference, ...){
    ...
    Child& child = static_cast<Child&>(parentReference);
```

(The class Child inherits directly and publicly from the class Parent)

I'd like to adjust the behavior of this cast - I can modify the class Child.
I've tried overloading the cast operator like so:

```
Parent::operator Child&(){
    ...
```

But this method never gets called.

I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible?

**EDIT**
Per R Sahu, I'm close to this scenario:
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.static.cast#2

```
struct B { };
struct D : public B { };
D d;
B &br = d;

static_cast<D&>(br);            // produces lvalue to the original d object
```

Except that instead of simply assigning `B &br = d;`, `br` comes into the method as an argument, and is previously sent over the network (as NML).

This would be the scenario:

```
struct B { };
struct D : public B { 
   int a;
   int b
};

D d;
d.a = x;
d.b = y;

server.send(d); 

...

client.receive(msg);

receive(B& msg){

  D& msgD = static_cast<D&>(msg);

}
```

`msgD.x` and `msgD.y` come over the wire and are reconstructed properly.  However, I would like to change the way they are reconstructed, without modifying the `receive` method.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you can't modify `Parent`, then the compiler shouldn't even let you define `Parent::operator Child&()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to overload the \*static\_cast\* operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432651/is-it-possible-to-overload-the-static-cast-operator)

Comment: @Brain - yeah, that was a mistake - I've edited accordingly. I actually can modify Parent.

Comment: you need to modify reconstruction, so do so. usually it's called de-serialisation. or show us how it's done

Answer (score 0):

Given classes

```
struct Parent
{
};

struct Child : Parent
{
};
```

`static_cast<Child&>` will not use a user defined conversion function.

From [5.2.9 Static cast/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.static.cast#2)

> An lvalue of type “cv1 B,” where B is a class type, can be cast to type “reference to cv2 D,” where D is a class derived from B, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists , cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1, and B is neither a virtual base class of D nor a base class of a virtual base class of D. The result has type “cv2 D.”

and then there are the "otherwise" clauses in [5.2.9 Static cast/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.static.cast#4) and [5.2.9 Static cast/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.static.cast#5).

My interpretation of the above is that since `Child` is a sub-type of `Parent`, the clauses 4 and 5 above don't apply.

Comment: Then how come `Child child3 = static_cast<Child>(parent);` calls 
`Parent::operator Child&(){...`

Comment: @fatman, I updated the answer just a tad. `static_cast<Child>` is different than `static_cast<Child&>`.

Comment: @R Sahu - thanks for the reply - it helped shine a light on exactly what I am trying to do.  I've added more detail to my question above.